# How to create Post model with 2 model User/Admin rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 models (not STI) `User` and `Admin`. Now I want to create blog post (`Post` model) with both `User and Admin`. Is it impossible? Or any solution exists?

I tried some solution as:

- Create `User` and `AdminUser`(STI model) (but i want to have 2 model User/Admin)
- Create `Post` with(user_id, admin_id) (it seems to waste memory for null value)
- Create `Post` and `AdminPost`(STI model) (but i think it is hard to manage)

Anyone have experiences or suggestion for this problem? It is appreciated.

Comment: "Create Post with(user_id, admin_id) (it seems to waste memory for null value)". This is probably the most straight-forward answer. Are you really worried about `null` values in your database? Why is that a significant problem?

Comment: yep, I think if I have 10,000 Post with (user_id: 1, admin_id: null) , it will take me much unnecessary memory. Is that right? @jvillian

Comment: Some expert will hopefully weigh in. But, I think (based on some quick research) with 10,000 rows will have negligible impact on memory and storage. If this is a problem you *think* you *might* eventually have, then I would suggest either (1) researching it more before you try to solve what may be a non-existent, future problem, or (2) go work on some real problem that you currently have.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a polymorphic model would be good?

Post could belong to an association that relates it to other models(in this case User and Admin). Maybe call it `postable` - or something better.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :posts, as: :postable
end

class Admin < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :posts, as: :postable
end
```

You can look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) for more info.